I am practice ipcRenderer but I can not see the result which i think would happen
I am a student and actually English is not my native language so there must be lots of grammer problem I'm so sorry.And just like what I wrote on title I'm learning how to use ipcRenderer but it didn't work.I mean when I press the button the application doesn't quit.And I have try just console.log(), when I press button.It of course can work.However,After I addrequire("electron").ipcRenderer.send('close').Not only when i press button the application do not quit, but also it don't cout any thing.
Here are my program
合庫8858.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/sidebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/合庫8858.css">
    <title>合庫8858</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="te"><p>close</p></button>
    <script src="script/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script/合庫8858.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

合庫8858.js:
$(".te").on('click', ()=>{
    require("electron").ipcRenderer.send('close')
    $(".te").css('background-color', 'black')
})

main.js:
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')
//const { electron } = require('node:process')
const electron = require('electron')
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  const loading = new BrowserWindow({
    width:600,
    height:400,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    },
    frame:false,
    show:false
  })
  loading.loadFile('waiting.html')
  loading.once('ready-to-show', () =>{
    loading.show()
  })
  
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    },
    show:false,
    frame:true
  })
  
  electron.Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)
  mainWindow.loadFile('合庫8858.html')
  
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () =>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      //mainWindow.maximize()
      loading.hide()
      loading.close()
      mainWindow.show()
    }, 500);  
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

ipcMain.on('close', ()=>{
  app.quit()
})

I am really confuse that what happen.Thank you for helping me.
Hope someone can tell me what wrong or if I make some silly mistake.
I have ask this question one time before, but I don't know who closed my question.
Actually, I am new here.Does it offen happen(question be closed).This time I try to make my question more detailed.
Please somebody help me solve this problem.and don't ban the question.QQ

have you read this answer? the comment from Feb 2022 may illuminate you - note: this was the first search result for the phrase "close electron app from renderer" - surprised you didn't come across that when you researched your issue

@JaromandaX This is a bad answer using require in the renderer, which is not possible by default for security reasons. OP does the exact same thing here and it's one of the reasons why it is not working. There is an error in the console saying so.

I am so sorry by wasting your time. As I wrote ,i am new here I just focus on finding ipcrenderer,and do not notice that i can just find "Close Electron app on click event".I have solve my problem thank you very much

This question is similar to: Close Electron app on click event. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
